# printf statement error

Tags: c

my last printf statement is not printing I'm not sure what's wrong since I'm using getchar to read the standard input, I must also use %s for this problem. I'm trying to make the last printf statement print the exact input from standard input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 16

// Input: pointer to the the old_Buffer i.e. *buffer and the pointer to the old_Buffer size i.e. *buffer_size
// Output: pointer to the new_Buffer i.e. *temp
// Summary: Function to increase the buffer size to double whenever the old_Buffer reaches the max possible size
char* IncreaseBuffer(char *buffer,int *buffer_size){

// Creating a new buffer of double the size
int temp_sz = *buffer_size;
temp_sz = 2*temp_sz;
char *temp;
temp = realloc(buffer, temp_sz);

// If the allocation is not successful, then exit the program and print the error
if (!temp) {
    printf("Error: Unable to Realloc\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Update the buffer size as per the new buffer and return the new buffer instead of the old buffer
*buffer_size = temp_sz;
return temp;
}

int main(void){
// INITIAL BUFFER
char *myString;
myString = malloc(INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE);
int curr_size = INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE;

// TEMPORARY CHARACTER TO STORE THE READ CHARACTER
char ch;
printf("Enter a string: ");

// Number of buffer increases
int buff_inc = 0;

// Length of the string
int len = 0;

while((ch=getchar())!=EOF){
    if(ch == '\n'){
        // If character read is a new line, then we break and assume that we have got our string to print by now
        break;
    }else{
        if(len >= curr_size - 1){
            // If length of the string is greater than the buffer size, then we increase the buffer size
            // Also increment the number of buffer increases
            myString = IncreaseBuffer(myString, &curr_size);
            buff_inc++;
        }
        // Append the read character to the end of the buffer
        myString[len++] = ch;
    }
}

printf("String size: %d\n", len);
printf("Buffer increases: %d\n", buff_inc);
printf("You entered: %s\n",myString);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to NULL ('\0') terminate the string.

Comment: thank you for your help. however, I'm still not printing the last printf statement of You entered:

Comment: @UmamaheshP: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant. `'\0'` is the null character.

Comment: hi, can you guys assist me with the last printf statement? i'm really confused why it's not printing?

Answer (score 2):

You ***must not*** free the old buffer after calling `realloc`.  That is bad.  It has already been resized and memory allocation taken care of.  It might even keep the same address after reallocation.

Just remove the following lines:

```
// Free the old buffer
free(buffer);
buffer = NULL;
```

And, already pointed out in the comments, you forgot to terminate your string.  Do this after the loop:

```
myString[len] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Trimmed down after just seeing @paddy's answer, but for the record this is from the [realloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) docs:

> **On success**, returns the pointer to the beginning of newly allocated memory. The returned pointer must be deallocated with free() or realloc(). **The original pointer ptr is invalidated and any access to it is undefined behavior** (even if reallocation was in-place).
>
> On failure, returns a null pointer. The original pointer ptr remains valid and may need to be deallocated with free() or realloc().